# cq5 include a component inside another component

Tags: extjs, aem

I usually use `<cq:include path="fakepath" resourceType="/project/components/testcomponent" />` to include a component inside a another component, named it as "setComponent".

Assume, "setComponent" drag and dropped onto a page and no data entered yet.

Question 1:

First thing is the **"testcomponent" resource does not exist at the /content tree page level and I see GET request to "fakepath.infinity.json" when I double click "testcomponent" to enter data, and this GET request is failing (404 error in browser developer tool console).
Not sure, whether it is expected behavior.**

Question 2:

How can I include component "/apps/project/components/testcomponent"
inside a parent component using below tags ?

```
<sling:include path="" />
<sling:include resource="" />
<sling:include path="" resourceType="" />
```

I am educating myself to properly understand and trying to see if sling:include could get rid of 404 error that I am talking.

Thank you,
Sri

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<div>
     <cq:include path="navMenu"       
      resourceType="sampleproj/components/common/testMenu" />
</div>
```

pseudocode for testMenu jsp:

```
  <%@page session="false"%>
  <%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
  <%@ page import="com.day.cq.commons.Doctype,
    com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageFilter,
    com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Navigation" %>
  <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href='navitempath.html'><div>navitemtitle</div></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove extra '/' symbol from resourceType

```
<cq:include path="fakepath" resourceType="project/components/testcomponent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use sling:include you are loading an existing node from other path.
For example :
`<sling:include path="./mycomponentpath" resourceType="/apps/company/components/componentName"/>`

mycomponentpath is a node created previously, and you are injecting this content in your actual component.

You can use `<cq:include path="fakepath" resourceType="/project/components/testcomponent" />` if you want include and empty component within other component.

I need more information to help you. Could you copy the testcomponent jsp ?